# WPDataTable (Wordpress) - Value Label in Google Pie Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I created a chart in the "Wp Data Chart" but my client wants the value in absolute number and not percentage, how would I change it? I managed to change the color by making a call back

To change the color of the chart I used this code below, how would I change the label to absolute value?

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function(){ 
    if( typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined' ){ wpDataChartsCallbacks = {}; } 
    wpDataChartsCallbacks[3] = function(obj){ 
         obj.options.colors = [

                     '#00544d',

                     '#a88F0a',

                     '#a33d05',

                     '#9eab05',

                     '#165788',

                     '#44748f'


        ];


        obj.options.labels =['Value']; 
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: what config options are used to draw the chart?

Comment: @WhiteHat The "WpDataChart" Follows a pattern, I didn't make a code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the callback, remove the following line...

```
obj.options.labels =['Value'];
```

and add...

```
obj.options.pieSliceText = 'value';
```

see following snippet...

```
    jQuery(window).load(function(){ 
            if( typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined' ){ wpDataChartsCallbacks = {}; } 
            wpDataChartsCallbacks[3] = function(obj){ 
                     obj.options.colors = [
                             '#00544d',
                             '#a88F0a',
                             '#a33d05',
                             '#9eab05',
                             '#165788',
                             '#44748f'
                    ];

                    obj.options.pieSliceText = 'value'; 
            }
    });
```